# how to show angularjs ui calendar listview

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show my events in a list with angularjs angular-ui-calendar. I understand this is possible in the fullcalendar. I have read the documentation from https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ and https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/README.md but they do not show how to view data in a list like is done on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view 
I would like to know wether angular-ui-calendar supports this listview and if so how do i go about it.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        editable: false,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        height: "auto",
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },          
        viewRender: function (view, element) {},
        eventClick: $scope.alertOnEventClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
        eventRender: $scope.eventRender
    }
};
```

in my html

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="dataSources"
     calendar="myCalender">
</div>
```

i then load data from my server

```
loaddata().then(function (r) {
    $scope.dataSources = r;
});
```